# Concourse Pipeline Not Retrieving Configuration Values from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, cicd, pipeline, secret-management

I'm experiencing an issue where my Concourse pipeline isn't picking up configuration values from AWS Secrets Manager. I have set everything up according to the documentation, ensured the necessary IAM roles and permissions are in place, but the secrets expected from Secrets Manager are not being retrieved or recognized during the pipeline's job executions.

Here's an overview of my setup:

1. I've confirmed that the IAM roles and policies attached to my
   Concourse components have the necessary permissions to access
   Secrets Manager.
2. The secret identifiers in my pipeline configuration
   match those in Secrets Manager. I've attempted to force the pipeline
   to refresh and check for new versions of the secrets, but this
   hasn't resolved the issue.

Here's a snippet of the test program I'm using:
jobs:

```
- name: test-secret-fetch
  plan:
  - task: use-secret
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: registry-image
        source: {repository: alpine}
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Using secret: $SECRET"
      params:
        SECRET: ((my-secret-key))
```

And I've set the following secret in AWS Secrets Manager:

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret --name "/concourse/sandbox/test-secret/my-secret-key" --secret-string "my-secret-value"
```

However, when I trigger the pipeline, the expected secret isn't being retrieved. Below is the Concourse value file I'm using (with sensitive values redacted):

```
imagePullSecrets: ["org-registry"]
persistence:
  enabled: true
  worker:
    size: "100Gi"
secrets:
  create: true
  localUsers: "ciuser:REDACTED"
  githubClientId: "REDACTED"
  githubClientSecret: "REDACTED"
  awsSecretsmanagerAccessKey: "REDACTED"
  awsSecretsmanagerSecretKey: "REDACTED"
concourse:
  web:
    # ... configuration ...
    awsSecretsManager:
      enabled: true
      region: "eu-west-2"
      accessKey: "REDACTED"
      secretKey: "REDACTED"
      pipelineSecretTemplate: "/concourse/{{.Team}}/{{.Pipeline}}/{{.Secret}}"
    # ... additional configuration ...
    env:
      - name: AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG
        value: "true"
      - name: CONCOURSE_AWS_SECRETSMANAGER_ACCESS_KEY
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: aws-credentials
            key: access-key-id
      - name: CONCOURSE_AWS_SECRETSMANAGER_SECRET_KEY
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: aws-credentials
            key: secret-access-key
```

We're deploying using the following Helm command:

```
helm install cicd concourse/concourse -f concourse-values-final.yaml -n cicd --version 17.2.0 --debug
```

My questions are:

1. Are there any known issues with Concourse's integration with AWS
   Secrets Manager that might be causing this behavior?
2. Is there a potential caching mechanism or a delay in secret updates from AWS
   Secrets Manager that I need to account for?
3. What further diagnostic steps can I take to more precisely identify the cause of this issue?

Any insights or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.